# Select multiple found in listview subtitems

Tags: c#, listviewitem

I have this code but I can't highlight (with red) all the matches byteSize.

How I can automatically highlight them if found?

Thank you.

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in LV.Items)
{
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(lvi.SubItems[3].Text);
         
    var byteSize = info.Length;

    if (byteSize > 16 || byteSize < 16 || byteSize == 0) //check if keyfile is valid
    {
        MessageBox.Show("invalid key file", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        LV.Focus();
        lvi.SubItems[3].ForeColor = Color.Red;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (byteSize > 16 || byteSize < 16 || byteSize == 0)` is the same as `if (byteSize != 16)`.

Comment: You have `return;` in the middle of the loop, so only the very first match would become red.  Do you ever get a match and a subsequent MessageBox?

Comment: Alright it worked :) thank you so much. I just moved the "return;"

Comment: Do you even need a return?...

Comment: Yes. if I can't return. it throws an error

Comment: ...and what error would that be?  Show more surrounding code.

Comment: The error is from my AES Decrypter Class. if the key is invalid it's showing an error.
Later I will show you when I'm on my computer.

Comment: Nevermind. I just actually changed this. When I adding new items it will automatically denied invalid key file. 
later I'll show you my little changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final changes instead of checking in listview.
I just check first when adding new items.
It will return if key is invalid

```
private void AddToListsView(string Dir)
    {
        string folder = Dir;
        List<string> keyPath = new List<string>();
        
        foreach (var key in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.key"))
        {
            Fileinfo info = new Fileinfo(key);
            var byteSize = info.length;
            
            if  if (byteSize != 16)
            {
                return;
            }

            keyPath.Add(key);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `return` is still questionable here.  As written, once a file size has been found that is NOT 16, then NO MORE files will be processed.  The `foreach` loop is completely abandoned.  If you want to SKIP files that are not length 16, and continue processing the rest of the files in the `foreach` loop, then change the `return` to a [continue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue).  Alternatively, you can reverse the logic and only add items with a length of 16: `if (byteSize == 16) { keyPath.Add(key); }`...then just get rid of the `return`.